# Scroll collection view to index when collectionview paging is enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am using `UICollectionView` and has set paging enabled for it. 
For example I have 21 items in the `UICollectionView` each page contain 7 item so there are in all 3 pages...
Is there a way to `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` only if index is not in current page...
I am using below code which is scrolling the `UICollectionView` for every index.

```
[collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
```

Comment: you want scroll page wise right? each page contain 7 item and you want scroll to next 7 items right?

Comment: yes I want to scroll page wise

Comment: Is there a fix that there will be only seven items per page? Or it will changed to 8 items or 6 items?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems` whether your target indexPath is visible or not then scroll if necessary

Answer (score 0):

try this, hope this helps

first get the index, and then get the page by dividing the total item per page and then scroll to visible rect by using the page number, for example,

```
- (IBAction)scroll:(id)sender
  {
    int item = 89; //item to scroll (21 will be your case) and item might be any idea of cell
    int page = item/15; //15 is the total number of visible cell per page (7 will be your case)
    CGRect frameRect = self.collectionView.frame;
    CGFloat xPos = frameRect.origin.x + (frameRect.size.width * page); //calculate the position where that cell is present
    frameRect.origin.x = xPos;
   [self.collectionView scrollRectToVisible:frameRect animated:YES];//finally scroll the collection view
 }
```